# .NET Core IISIntegration configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

Pretty new to .NET Core, and am trying to understand how everything works together when using IIS integration.

A couple of questions: If I want my site to run over HTTPS, do i need to configure my WebBuilder with a certificate, or should i be selecting HTTPS on the binding in IIS manager, or both?

Does the UseUrls WebBuilder method also instruct IIS what port is should listen on? How does IIS know which port it should talk to the .NET Core application on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you host your .NET Core app behind IIS, IIS is acting as a reverse proxy to Kestrel web server. IIS will receive the HTTP request and pass it to Kestrel, the magic happen inside a new IIS module called AspNetCoreModule that you have to install on your server. As usual, to configure your IIS application you'll be using a web.config file in which you'll find a description of how IIS is interacting with your app: timeouts, pathes of the application, environment variables and so on... For instance, mine look like that:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore
      requestTimeout="00:20:00"
      processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
      arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
      stdoutLogEnabled="false"
      stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
      forwardWindowsAuthToken="true">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="development" /> <!-- value could be "development", "staging" or "production"-->
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
```

The reason why you want to set it up that way is that Kestrel is a very light weight and nervous web server but it's missing a layer of applicative features that IIS can add up: Windows authentication via Kerberos, restarting the app in case of a crash, pool management...

I like a lot this article regarding this topic: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

For HTTPS, it's enough to configure IIS to listen on a secure HTTPS port and to define the certificate only on IIS.

UseUrls() won't be taken into account by IIS, it will work the other way around, IIS will tell your app on which port it should be listening to, UseUrls() will be taken into account if you launch your app directly.

Comment: Ok.  Maybe that is one of my missing pieces.  I installed the ASP.NET Core 1.1 RunTime.  Does that not install the necessary module?

Comment: Nope, you need the Windows Server Hosting, see the bottom of the release note: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.0.5-download.md