# .NET Core website shutting down unexpectedly

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-core, iis

I've got a .NET Core website hosted by IONOS on Windows which seemingly shuts down unexpectedly at random.

I'm logging the following events as well as all incoming requests:

- IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted
- IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping
- IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped

As a result, I can see that my website restarts after receiving the following request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:37065/iisintegration
```

I've got no idea which process is behind this request, however given it uses 127.0.0.1 as the IP address, it must be local to the server.

Does anyone know anything about requests to `iisintegration`? Is it part of the ASP.NET Core stack? Any idea who might be sending such request? Could it be specific to IONOS? (their support is unhelpful).

Maybe relevant, here's the content of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I don't think it's related to IIS idle timeout: one request would be served successfully, then the next second I would see the application stopping.

Comment: Are you using this [iisintegration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration?view=aspnetcore-5.0)? What about iisintegration in your project? there are many reasons for website restart, this link may be helpful to you: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052428/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052428/13336642).

Comment: @samwu, it's probably hosted in IIS, but don't know for sure and don't have access because the website is hosted by a third party (IONOS). (I only have FTP access)

Comment: base on this message, It seems difficult to reproduce your problem.

Comment: any news? I'm also facing this problem.

Comment: this happens to me as well using www.myasp.net web hosting. Seems like they're setting application pool recycling when it hits a certain condition, probably to prevent you from using too many resources on their shared servers. Just a hunch.